# How to draw the image of a Möbius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{2z}{z+2}$. What is the image of the circle with radius 2 centered at 0?

I find that $f$ maps $2\to1$, $-2 \to \infty$. Hence, the image should be a line. Therefore, I pick another point on the circle, say $2i$, and find $f(2i)$. Then the line through $1$ and $f(2i)$ is the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function goes from the z in the w plane, so we need to find z to substitute in the circle equation.
$$w = \frac{2z}{z+2} \Rightarrow z = \frac{2w}{2-w}$$
The equation for the circle is $|z|=2 \Rightarrow |z|^2=4 \Rightarrow z\overline{z} = 4$. Substitute the inverse function:
$$\left(\frac{2w}{2-w}\right)\overline{\left(\frac{2w}{2-w}\right)} = 4$$
$$\left(\frac{2w}{2-w}\right)\left(\frac{2\overline{w}}{2-\overline{w}}\right) = 4$$
$$4w\overline{w} = 16 -8\overline{w} -8w + 4w\overline{w}$$
$$8w+8\overline{w} = 16$$
then let $w = u + vi$:
$$8(u+vi)+8(u-vi)=16$$
And the result is $u=1$

$f(2) = 1$ and $f(2i) = 1 + i$ so you get the same line.

Comment: I really don't get your last two sentences.

Comment: f(-2) is 4/0, but OP wrote it was $\infty$, which would not lay on the line $u=1$. So I took a point very close to -2, and laying on the circle. I am however only in the equivalent of a high-school and english is not my native language, so I may miss something or don't explain correctly. Feel free to edit if I made a mistake about the $\infty$ thing

Comment: can you detail your computation of $f(-1.99999+0.00632455i)$ ?

Comment: I rechecked it and I think I made an error (rechecked with Mathematica). Also, Mathematica says it approaches ComplexInfinity the closer I get to -2 so I removed the last lines.